# Django 4.0.1 models.py самостоятельно добавляет в бд поле "id"

Tags: python, django, mongodb

мой код в models.py проекта django:

```
from django.db import models

class Articles(models.Model):
    ArticleID = models.CharField('ArticleID', max_length=50)
    EmployeeName = models.CharField('EmployeeName', max_length=50)
    Department = models.CharField('Department', max_length=50)
```

После проведения миграций и добавления данных в БД появляется следующая структура:

```
id:13
ArticleID:"12"
EmployeeName:"20"
Department:"574"
```

Как убрать добавление поля 'id' в бд либо заменять его на 'ArticleID', чтобы осталась следующая структура:

```
ArticleID:"12"
EmployeeName:"20"
Department:"574"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В классе обозначить поле для `primary_key`

```py
from django.db import models

class Articles(models.Model):
    ArticleID = models.CharField('ArticleID', max_length=50, primary_key=True) # здесь
    EmployeeName = models.CharField('EmployeeName', max_length=50)
    Department = models.CharField('Department', max_length=50)
```

[В данном примере](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#quick-example) объясняется данное поведение. Если вы не определяете явно `primary_key`, то автоматически добавляется поле `id` с автоинкрементом уникальных значений

из доки

> If you don’t specify primary_key=True for any fields in your model, Django will automatically add an IntegerField to hold the primary key, so you don’t need to set primary_key=True on any of your fields unless you want to override the default primary-key behavior.

Перевод

> Если вы не указали `primary_key=True` для одного из полей вашей модели, Джанго автоматически добавит поле `IntegerField`  для хранения первичного ключа, так что вам нет необходимости устанавливать `primary_key=True` для какого либо поля до тех пор пока вам не понадобится переопределить поведение `primary-key` по умолчанию.

Comment: все равно добавляется данное поле

Comment: Я удалил файл с миграциями, удалил коллекцию в бд. Она создалась заново и все равно добавилось данное поле причем с последующим порядковым номером. (на данный момент 15)

Comment: миграции не забывайте

Comment: Проводил python manage.py makemigrations

Comment: а python manage.py migrate? Все ок? А что со старыми записями?

Comment: на migrate тоже все ок. Возможно в самой бд есть запись, потому что на сайт выводится уже без данного поля 'id'. Попробую удалить бд и начать заново.

Comment: @ВадимКривенко если есть такая возможность - то это лучшее для быстроты.

Comment: да, все сработало. Спасибо

Comment: @ВадимКривенко на здоровье, обратите внимание [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). На SO не принято говорить "спасибо" в комментариях=)